# How to call external java operations in Sirius

Tags: java, ecore, eclipse-sirius

I am designing an editor for a DSL using Sirius , I would like to know  how to call java methods from the odesign and store the content returned by the Java methods.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a Java service, add its fully-qualified name to the odesign and then call it. [Here](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/specifier/general/Writing_Queries.html#service_methods) is the documentation to do this.

Comment: No , I am talking about how can I use the External Java Action.

Comment: In that case, look up the documentation [here](https://www.eclipse.org/sirius/doc/specifier/general/Model_Operations.html#external_java_action), but services are usually enough for most needs.